# add Event Listener to array of elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, addeventlistener

```
if (btns.length && sections.length > 0) {

  btns[0].addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    smoothScrollTo(sections[0], event);
  });
  btns[1].addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    smoothScrollTo(sections[1], event);
  });
  btns[2].addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    smoothScrollTo(sections[2], event);
  });
  btns[3].addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    smoothScrollTo(sections[3], event);
  });
}
```

Hello friends  lets say I have many more buttons! instead of coding each one of them how to make it in short! I am new in js...

Thanks

Comment: Research 'loops in JS'

Comment: or wait for someone to write the code for you, of course: anyway [loops 101: the for loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for)

Comment: You can use loop to create an event for each action https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp

Comment: @AjaySinghDeopa Please don't use W3Schools as a reference. Their articles are often outdated and sometimes just plain wrong. MDN is far more comprehensive and accurate: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loop through an array in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010840/loop-through-an-array-in-javascript)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan While I do agree with you it's sometimes hard for new developers to understand the MDN documentation while W3Schools does have a more casual approach for beginners. At least from my perspective.

Comment: if you don't mind that `casual approach` === `sometimes just plain wrong`, then it's a good resource

Comment: I agree it's more casual, but I'd rather have something accurate that teaches me how to interpret professional specifications, than something easy and wrong.

Answer (score 3):

I see a jQuery TAG over there, isn't it?

```
$(btns).click(function(event) {
    smoothScrollTo(sections[$(this).index()], event);
});
```

It would be better if you add the index into the button as attribute, or with an ID, to prevent any problem...

Answer (score -2):

You need to create an anonymous function to pass the `i` variable.

```js
if (btns.length && sections.length > 0) {
  var l = btns.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
    btns[i].addEventListener('click', function(event) {
      (function(_i) {
        smoothScrollTo(sections[_i], event);
      })(i);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: what for the self invoking function?

Comment: a bit late to use IIFE inside the listener ... when I say "a bit late" I mean, of course, completely and utterly late :p

Comment: because you can use the **i** var inside the event, the **i** var is changing in the loop

Comment: and when is the IIFE inside the event listener invoked? before or after `i == l` ? You need a refresher course in closures